# Overload operator| for fixed-size arrays?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

Consider the following:

```
template <typename T> struct template_adapter_t {};

template <int N> struct foo_adapter_t {
  template <typename T> static foo_t<T, N> adapt(T const&);
};
template <int N> template_adapter_t< foo_adapter_t<N> > foo();

template <typename Range, typename Adapter>
auto operator|(
  Range const& range,
  template_adapter_t<Adapter>(*)())
-> decltype(Adapter::adapt(range))
{ return Adapter::adapt(range); }
```

(So, what is going on here... I have a 'dummy' class, `template_adapter_t`, that serves only as a specialization limiter, a concrete helper class `foo_adapter_t`, a free function `foo` which returns a type of `template_adapter_t`, and an overload of `operator|` that is supposed to take anything on the LHS, and a pointer to a function that takes no parameters and returns some type of `template_adapter_t` on the RHS.)

When I try to use this:

```
int const values[] = { ... };
values | foo<2>;
```

...I get an error about invalid operands.

However, this works:

```
std::vector<int>{} | foo<2>;
```

This *also* works:

```
template <typename Range, int N>
auto operator|(
  Range const& range,
  foo_adapter_t<N> const& adapter)
-> decltype(adapter.adapt(range))
{ return adapter.adapt(range); }

values | foo_adapter_t<4>{};
```

...so the problem doesn't seem to be with matching on the LHS. In both cases, the RHS is also templated, but for some reason, the one taking a struct works, but the one taking a function does not.

What am I missing that the alternate invocations work but the first one doesn't? How can I make the first form work?

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/g/sFQfxr)

Comment: I cannot get the supposed working code to compile.  Can you please provide a [mcve] and also include the error message?

Comment: "What am I missing?" is a really broad question, if you think about it.  Are you asking about the error message?  If so, show the error message.  If not, perhaps you could improve on that quoted sentence.

Comment: Live example here: https://godbolt.org/g/sFQfxr (also now linked in the original text)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you can't overload operators for 2 pointers. At least one of the operand should be used-defined class (See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Overloaded_operators)).

In this line:

```
values | foo<2>;
```

`values` is a pointer to `const int`, `foo<2>` is a function pointer, thus no overloaded operator will be considered.

Comment: Sigh. Okay, at least that *explains* it; thanks! Any ideas on a different formulation to make that work, without having to explicitly construct an object (i.e. `foo<2>()` or `foo<2>{}`)? Alas, it needs to work in C++11, so no variable templates...

Comment: @Matthew Use function object to pattern match. Inside functor class, use trait to recover `Adapter`'s type, so SFINAE still works.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how to make that work. Maybe you can answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49639536?

Comment: @Matthew After reading that question, I don't think it's possible. My last comment is not related since I didn't understand what you were asking that time.