# Can I overload an operator taking a pointer and a non-constructed template object?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, operator-overloading

I would like to write some code like this:

```
some_container | foo<args...>;
```

For concreteness, let's say the RHS is `foo<2>`.

The tricky part is, `foo` is something that should be automatically instantiated. IOW, I "fail" if `foo<2>` has to be explicitly instantiated, or if I have to stick `()` or `{}` after it.

If the LHS is a class type, I can accomplish this by making `foo` a function returning a "tag" type, then providing a templated overload of `operator|`. However, this doesn't work (see [Overload operator| for fixed-size arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49638281) for the code I am currently using) if the LHS is also a pointer type, as is the case if it is a C-style array.

Is there any way ***in C++11*** (i.e. without using C++14 variable templates) to achieve this syntax?

The result of this expression ultimately needs to be :

```
bar<decltype(some_container), args...>{some_container}
```

(so e.g. `bar<int (&)[N], 2>` for LHS `int[N]` and RHS `foo<2>`).

Comment: Why not just write `foo<args...>{}`? it's just 2 more chars

Comment: Why the C++11 restriction? There's a reason why variable templates were added in C++14: to allow for syntax such as this.

Comment: ...because it's ugly? ...because I need to support pre-C++14 compilers? I'm also asking not because I desperately *need* to save those two characters, but because I am genuinely curious if it is *possible*. I don't think being curious if something can be done constitutes a bad question.

Comment: You *could* make `foo` a macro that expands into `bar | foo`, `bar` being a tag object with which you can overload on both sides. *Could*.

Comment: Yeah... no ;-). If we had namespaced macros, maybe I'd go there, but the identifier by itself is too likely to cause conflicts, and decorating it to avoid that would sort of defeat the purpose. (I *did* consider adding an identity, i.e. `values | identity | foo<...>`, which is along the same lines...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The syntax `foo<...>` can only be a class (or alias) template (which is an invalid expression) or function template (which becomes a function pointer, which you can’t overload for).

Comment: If we suppose this answer to be obvious, then this is a duplicate of your own, linked question.

Comment: liliscent seemed to think it was possible, and I didn't see how to ask in the comments of the other question without turning them into a primary discussion. However, a later comment notes that the question was not understood. I disclaim sufficient knowledge to opine if that makes this a duplicate or not. (At any rate, I think the clarification using this format was useful.)